# Mocking mixin classes in Grails

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, mocking

I am having some difficulty unit testing a controller.

I have the following objects:

```
class User {
    String username
}

class SecurityMixin {

    User userDetails(session) {
        User user = new User()
        user.username = 'somename'
        return user
    }
}

@Mixin(SecurityMixin)
class MyController {
    def index() {
        def username = userDetails(session).username

    }
}
```

How would I mock the `userDetails` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never done this with a mixin, maybe you can test it out. In your *ControllerTests

```
@Before
void setUp() {
  ..
  controller.metaClass.userDetails = {
    new User(username: 'somename')
  }
}
```